# Is there any runnable methods or script for Best practice to find out all commented code in D365?

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

can someone help me with a script or runnable class to find out all the commented code across the project module.

I tried out the manual way of going to each class and finding out the commented code , but its very time consuming. An automated script or something would make my work faster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quick and easy way to remove "dead" (commented out) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421041/quick-and-easy-way-to-remove-dead-commented-out-code) In this case, x++ is close enough to other languages to use this method to find commented code.